# How to dynamically add and remove a set of togglebuttons mui react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm kinda stuck at this issue, my goal is to let a user select multiple days as a condition so am using toggleButtons material-ui, the thing is I'm adding a plus button so the user can add another set of days or remove them. any idea how can I achieve this please ?

```
const [formats, setFormats] = useState(() => []);
const handleFormat = (event, newFormats) => {
setFormats(newFormats);

<ToggleButtonGroup value={formats} onChange={handleFormat} key={index}>
    <ToggleButton
        value="Monday"
        size="small"
        className={classes.buttonToggle}
    >
        <Typography className={classes.buttonToggle}>Lundi</Typography>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
        value="Tuesday"
        className={classes.buttonToggle}
        size="small"
    >
        <Typography className={classes.buttonToggle}>Mardi</Typography>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
        value="Wednesday"
        className={classes.buttonToggle}
        size="small"
    >
        <Typography className={classes.buttonToggle}>Mercredi</Typography>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
        value="Thursday"
        className={classes.buttonToggle}
        size="small"
    >
        <Typography className={classes.buttonToggle}>Jeudi</Typography>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
        value="Friday"
        className={classes.buttonToggle}
        size="small"
    >
        <Typography className={classes.buttonToggle}>Vendredi</Typography>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
        value="Saturday"
        className={classes.buttonToggle}
        size="small"
    >
        <Typography className={classes.buttonToggle}>Samedi</Typography>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
        value="Sunday"
        className={classes.buttonToggle}
        size="small"
    >
        <Typography className={classes.buttonToggle}>Dimanche</Typography>
    </ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-material-ui-forked-7ywim?file=/src/index.js) that allows you to add/select/remove days using MUI's `ToggleButton`.

Code looks like:

```
function App() {
  const [formats, setFormats] = useState([]);
  const [days, setDays] = useState([""]);

  const handleFormat = (event, newFormats, index) => {
    let res = [...formats];
    res[index] = newFormats;
    setFormats(res);
    console.log(res);
  };

  const removeDays = (index) => {
    let res = [...formats];
    res.splice(index, 1);
    setFormats(res);
    let dres = [...days];
    dres.splice(index, 1);
    setDays(dres);
  };

  const toggleDays = (index) => {
    return (
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        value={formats[index]}
        onChange={(e, newFormat) => handleFormat(e, newFormat, index)}
        key={index}
      >
        <Button onClick={() => removeDays(index)}>Remove</Button>
        <ToggleButton value="Monday" size="small">
          Lundi
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="Tuesday" size="small">
          Mardi
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="Wednesday" size="small">
          Mercredi
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="Thursday" size="small">
          Jeudi
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="Friday" size="small">
          Vendredi
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="Saturday" size="small">
          Samedi
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="Sunday" size="small">
          Dimanche
        </ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    );
  };

  const addDays = () => {
    let res = [...days];
    res.push("");
    setDays(res);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={() => addDays()}>Add</Button>
      <br />
      {days.map((x, index) => toggleDays(index))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The logic is quite simple:

`formats` is a matrix (array of arrays) of selected days; `days` is just an array of empty strings (I'm using it to count lines of days user wants to add).

Then I added a button called `Add` to add a line. Each line has a `Remove` button to cancel line.

When user adds a line I call `addDays` function that just add a new element to `days`. When user removes a line I call `removeDays` function that `splice` `days` and `formats` arrays.

`toggleDays` is the funciton that returns the `ToggleButtonGroup`.

The graphical result is:

[image]